# Refresh spinner/view after execute asynchronous task in another class

Tags: android, asynchronous

My apps has a spinner on the main activity, and the content is loaded from sqlite. And my apps do provide a download option for user to download latest data from server. And the asynchronous download task is in another class.

So my question is how do i refresh the main's activity spinner once the download process is completed?

Comment: pass the context of your activity to your download class

Comment: call your mainactivity again after download progress is completed

Comment: Activity act = (Activity)context;
        ((LinearLayout) act.findViewById(R.id.spinstore)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); i use this but it crashed when called these line

Comment: you might be using some kind of adaptor try dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();, also try to invalidate

Comment: @AbhinavRathore how do i call again my mainactivity, any code, please. sorry i'm new in java and android.

Comment: call this after downlaod progress is finished

Intent intent = new Intent(myactivity.this, myactivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

1) Create a callback interface

```
 public interface DownloadCompleted {
        // Define your Data type to which you want to store data after AsycTask completion
        public void onTaskComplete(String result);
    }
```

2) AsycTask

```
 public class UploadAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog Dialog;
        String response = "";
        Activity _context;
        private DownloadCompleted callback;

        public UploadAsyncTask (Activity _context) {
            this._context = _context;
            this.callback = (DownloadCompleted ) _context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog = new ProgressDialog(_context);
            Dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            Dialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                String url= urls[0];
                //Do your operation
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return response ;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Dialog.dismiss();
            callback.onTaskComplete(result);

        }

    }
```

3) Implement the interface in your calling Activity

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements DownloadCompleted {   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new UploadAsyncTask (this).execute(YOUR URL String);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.rss_reader, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
        // Refresh your view here
                // use result data as after completion AsycTask
    }

}
```

For more help and source code please go through the below link.

http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-rssfeed-with-async-task-example.html

Comment: Even i found my own answer, i think yours is better.! For those who intereseted on mine. protected void onPostExecute(String[] results) {
  progress.dismiss();  
 Activity act = (Activity)context;
 Spinner mspinstore ;
  mspinstore= (Spinner) act.findViewById(R.id.spinstore);  //do the rest of your code here}