# How to refresh ListView in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am using `AsyncTask` and fetch twitter feed asynchronously to display in a listView. It works fine Then for refreshing the listview I put the asyncTask call into a `Runnable`'s `Run()` to load it after a specific interval. The feed loads after specific time interval but the listview is not updating. I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the asyncTask but it is not working.

This is my trying code:

```
public class Twitter7FeedActivity extends Activity {

    LazyAdapter adapter;
    ListView list;
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_twitter7_feed);
        callAsynchronousTask();
    }

    public void callAsynchronousTask() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            new GetFeedTask().execute(CommonUtils.BEARER_TOKEN,
                                    CommonUtils.URL);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 50000);
    }

    protected class GetFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(
                Twitter7FeedActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // related code
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonText) {
            // related code 
            adapter = new LazyAdapter(Twitter7FeedActivity.this,
            // tweets);
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use notify adapter method

Comment: He already use it `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: may be you want to try this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472539/refresh-spinner-view-after-execute-asynchronous-task-in-another-class

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving this line:

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

after your setContentView in your onCreate method?

Comment: @Noor Azam, Your answer is not an answer. Put this type of confusion/suggestion in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

```
// related code adapter = new LazyAdapter(Twitter7FeedActivity.this, tweets);
```

uncomment this code which is in onPostExecute() method. I think it may help you out. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can do the work mentioned in your question using only a `Handler`.  Something like this:

```
public class Twitter7FeedActivity extends Activity {
LazyAdapter adapter;
ListView list;
JSONObject jsonObj = null;
JSONArray jsonArray = null;

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_twitter7_feed);
    callAsynchronousTask();
}

public void callAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        public void run() {
                    try {

                        //Show your dialog here
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                runnable.this.dialog = new ProgressDialog( Twitter7FeedActivity.this);
                                runnable.this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
                                runnable.this.dialog.show();
                            }

                         });

                        //Do your AsyncTask's doInBackground work here

                        //Update the UI with runOnUiThread or using the Ui threa handler
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                // related code adapter = new LazyAdapter(Twitter7FeedActivity.this, tweets);
                                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                                list.setAdapter(adapter); 
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                         });

                         //Then post the thread to excecute after 50000 milliseconds.
                         handler.postDelayed(runnable, 50000);
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    { }
                }
    };
    handler.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

This way you avoid using an `AsyncTask` inside a `TimerTask`.